# How can I create title with variable using Latex in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, latex, title

I have a Matlab code to generate a title representing the multiplication of two fractions using Latex.

```
t=title('$\frac{5}{2} \times \frac{3}{4}$');
set(t,'Interpreter','Latex');
```

My question is how to replace the numbers in Latex equation to variables?
For example, if I defined

```
A = 5;
B = 2;
C = 3;
D = 4;
```

How to use A,B,C,D to replace the numbers on the latex form title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to either use `[]` to concatenate the string

```
titlestr = ['$\frac{', num2str(A), '}{', num2str(B), '} \times \frac{', num2str(C), '}{', num2str(D)'}$'];
title(titlestr)
```

Or you can use `sprintf` but you'll have to be sure to escape all of the `\` characters

```
titlestr = sprintf('$\\frac{%d}{%d} \\times \\frac{%d}{%d}$', A, B, C, D);
title(titlestr)
```

Comment: `sprintf` is probably cleaner

Comment: FASTER! FASTER!